# Insertion Sort: Giving me none when I print

Tags: python, python-3.x, insertion-sort

I searched through stack, but I still can't get this to work. I'm learning how to construct algorithms and need to code an algroithm (using insertion sort) to sort the array in ascending order and display the value it contains. Currently I'm getting **None**.

```
 def sortedRainfall (rainfall):
        month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
                    ,'September','October','November','December']
        for index in range(1,len(rainfall)):
            value = rainfall[index]
            i = index - 1
            while (i >= 0):
                if value < rainfall[i]:
                    rainfall[i+1] = rainfall[i] #shift number in slot i right  to slot i + 1
                    rainfall[i] = value #shif value left into slot i
                    i = i - 1
                else:
                    break

        return
```

Full code is below:

```
#Main module --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main ():
    rainfall = rainInput () #Gets rainfall per month from user.
    totalRain = totalRainfall (rainfall) #Totals rainfall from user inputted data.
    average_Rainfall = averageRainfall (totalRain) #Averages rainfall for the year.
    highestMonth, highestMonthly = highestMonthNumber (rainfall) #Finds highest month of rainfall and displays to the user. 
    lowestMonth, lowestMonthly = lowestMonthNumber (rainfall) #Finds lowest month of rainfall and displays to the user. ---
    rainfallSorted = sortedRainfall(rainfall)
    print #this is for spacing output
    print ('The total rainfall for the year was: ' +str(totalRain) + ' inche(s)')
    print #this is for spacing output
    print ('The average rainfall for the year was: ' +str(average_Rainfall) +\
          ' inche(s)') 
    print #this is for spacing in output
    print ('The highest amount of rain was', highestMonthly, 'in' , highestMonth)
    print #this is for spacing in output
    print ('The lowest amount of rain was', lowestMonthly, 'in' , lowestMonth)
    print(rainfallSorted)


#Gets rainfall per month from user. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def rainInput ():
    rainfall = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
    ,'September','October','November','December']
    month = 0

    while month < len(rainfall):
        rainfall[month] = int(input ('Please enter the amount for month ' + str\
        (month + 1) + ': '))
        month += 1
        rainfall.append

    return rainfall

#Totals rainfall from user inputted data. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def totalRainfall (rainfall):
    return sum([int(x) for x in rainfall])

#Averages rainfall for the year. ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def averageRainfall (totalRain):
    average_Rainfall = totalRain / 12

    return average_Rainfall

#Finds highest month of rainfall and displays to the user. ----------------------------------------------------------------
def highestMonthNumber (rainfall):
    month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
                ,'September','October','November','December']
    highestMonthly = 0
    highestMonth = 0
    for m, n in enumerate(rainfall):
        if n > highestMonthly:
            highestMonthly = n
            highestMonth = m

    return month[highestMonth], highestMonthly

#Finds lowest month of rainfall and displays to the user. -----------------------------------------------------------------
def lowestMonthNumber (rainfall):
    month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
                ,'September','October','November','December']
    lowestMonthly = 1000000000
    lowestMonth = 0
    for m, n in enumerate(rainfall):
        if n < lowestMonthly:
            lowestMonthly = n
            lowestMonth = m

    return month[lowestMonth], lowestMonthly

def sortedRainfall (rainfall):
    month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
                ,'September','October','November','December']
    for index in range(1,len(rainfall)):
        value = rainfall[index]
        i = index - 1
        while (i >= 0):
            if value < rainfall[i]:
                rainfall[i+1] = rainfall[i] #shift number in slot i right  to slot i + 1
                rainfall[i] = value #shif value left into slot i
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break

    return

main()
```

Comment: since you aren't returning anything in the sortedRainfall function.. so None

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `sorted` function?

Comment: No. I wish I could :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sortedRainfall (rainfall):

for i in range(1, len(rainfall)):
    if rainfall[i] < rainfall[i-1]:
        for j in range(i):
            if rainfall[i] < rainfall[j]:
                rainfall[i], rainfall[j] = rainfall[j], rainfall[i]
return rainfall
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def sortNames(listOfNames):
    sortedNames = []
    for index in range(1,len(listOfNames)):
        value = listOfNames[index]
        i = index - 1
        while (i >= 0):
            if value < listOfNames[i]:
                listOfNames[i+1] = listOfNames[i] #shift number in slot i right  to slot i + 1
                listOfNames[i] = value #shif value left into slot i
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break
    return rainfall
```

Just had to return something.

Comment: (Psst, you should mark as solution, if you found the solution).